# Will most Distros run on an old pentium d?

Tags: linux, x86

I am starting out in Linux for my first time and i'm wanting to know if the old Pentium D w/ p35 chipset will be compatible for most distros.  It will be my "training" computer as I learn Linux. I am not looking to run high end video or modeling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, a Pentium D is an [x86-64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64), and all generations of this architecture should be supported by current distributions.

With 32-bit processors, you can go back to the first 686 ([P6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P6_(microarchitecture)) generation, i.e. Pentium Pro, without trouble. Previous series (Pentium, 486) are not supported by all current distributions — at least you'll need a kernel that doesn't say `686`. Recent versions of the kernel have dropped support for the 386 generation, so you'll need to fish out an old distribution for this.

If you have a computer that's running Windows, you can install a virtual machine and play with Linux inside it. [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) is a good choice of VM for this. A really recent computer may run Linux faster in a VM than a Pentium D, but the VM does slow things down a bit and can be cumbersome at times.

Another way to play with Linux is with cheap hardware such as a [Raspberry Pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi). A Pentium D is more powerful than a Pi though, so I'm only mentioning this for the sake of future visitors with an older processor (such as a Pentium, which is slower than a Pi).